# Problems installing python packages on Mac M1

Tags: python, macos

I want to install python packages listed in the requirements file of my github repo. However, I have problems installing those python packages into my conda environment.

First of all, I installed conda with Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64 which supports the M1 with arm64 architecture. However, some specific python packages like onnxruntime I wasn't able to install, because I encountered error messages like that:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime
```

I assumed that for those specific python packages there is no support yet for the M1.

Therefore, I pursued another approach. I set the settings of Terminal to "Open with Rosetta". The plan is to install the applications of the intel x86_64 architecture and let Rossetta create the binaries to let run on arm64. Then I uninstalled miniforge for arm64 and installed miniforge for x86_64 named Miniforge3-MacOSX-x86_64. With that setup I was able to install all listed python packages of the requirement file and with `pip freeze` I can also confirm that they have been installed. However, I am somehow not able to use those python packages. For instance if I want to run pytest I get the following error:

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction pytest
```

I assumed Rossetta takes care of that, that I can use applications for x86_64 also on arm64. But somehow it doesn't work. I tried a lot of different things and am out of ideas.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I would be also thankful for advice and suggestions how to properly set up a python environment on Mac M1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem back in 2days ago, I'm using `m1 pro`. I was trying to install the python packages only using `pip` but I got a numbers of errors, then I decided to install with `conda`.

In my case it worked, here is what I've done so far is:

First Enable the `open with rosetta` in your zsh.
And then,

```sh
# create environment in conda
conda create -n venv python=3.8 # with your python version

# activate
conda activate venv
```

and visit the conda website to look for the packages:
[check packages](https://anaconda.org/)

For suppose if you are looking for `pytest` packages then you can search it, and you'll get a result like this, with the available package and channel.

[image]

You need to enable that specific channel to get that package with this command:

```sh
# config channel
conda config --append channels conda-forge # available channel name

# then install
conda install --yes --file requirements.txt
```

Make sure, your have the same version of `pytest` in your `requirements.txt` file. `(eg:pytest==6.2.5)`

Hope this should work, if not try to install it with `pip` like:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
after environment enable.

Comment: Hi Pradip, thanks a lot for your answer! I installed miniforge by downloading the installer from here: https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge And then executing the shell script. Did you install **Miniforge3-MacOSX-x86_64** or **Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64** ?

Comment: @beayze, No I didn't. It won't required in my case.

Comment: just to be sure and to exclude sources of error for better troubleshooting. You used **miniforge** to install conda and the version for the **arm64** architecture?

Comment: I dont have much idea about it, maybe I've used this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pradip, your answer solved the problem. It seems that the channel conda-forge supports arm64 for a great amount of python packages. I discovered it even supports tensorflow. That might be a replacement for the tensorflow metal workaround.

Comment: @PradipDhakal - conda worked for me. Your tip was good. However I also needed other packages which were not in conda forge, so used pip inside a conda. Not sure how that messes up my env, but things working for now. thanks.